# function as an optional parameter python

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

i am trying to write a function to check if a parameter was passed to it (which is a function ) if so call that function with an argument else if **there wasn't any argument given** return a value so my approach was like this :

```py
def nine(fanc=None):
    if(fanc!=None): return fanc(9,fanc) 
    return 9
```

but this code rise an error which is :

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

i know that this approach isn't correct but i couldn't find any other way to do so
i have also tried using `*args` this way but end up with the same results :

```py
def nine(*args):
    if(len(args)!=0): return args[0](9,args) 
    return 9
```

Comment: Can you please be a bit  more clear about what you want

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee i want to write a function  that has  a function as an optional argument so i 'd be able to either pass to it function or call it without any

Comment: Could you please add some example calls to the function, that is, examples of how you plan to use the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to guess what you want but this snippet might help you:

```
def fct(**kwargs):
    if 'func' in kwargs:
        f = kwargs['func']
        return f(9)
    else:
        return 9

def f(x):
    return x**2
    
print(fct())  # result = 9
print(fct(func=f))  # result = 81
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `callable` built-in function, consider following example

```
def investigate(f=None):
    if callable(f):
        return "I got callable" 
    return "I got something else"
print(investigate())
print(investigate(min))
```

output:

```
I got something else
I got callable
```

Beware that callable is more broad term that function, as it also encompass objects which have `__call__` method.

Comment: `callable` does not guarantee that it's a function, just that the `__call__` method is implemented. Instead, `types.FunctionType` should be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the passed argument is a function and, if yes, then execute it with fixed arguments, you could try the following:

```py
from typing import Union
from types import FunctionType

def nine(func: Union[FunctionType, None] = None):
    if type(func) is FunctionType:
        return func(9) 
    return 9
```